# Incompatible coordinate charts on the two dimensional sphere

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Most of the examples of the charts for $S^2$ involve compatible ones like:

1. Stereographic projections from the North and South Pole.
2. Projections onto the disk bound by the equator.

What would be simplest example of two coordinate charts for $S^2$ that are NOT compatible with each other?

Comment: Stereographic for upper hemisphere and 2. for the lower?

Comment: Are you asking for an analog of the identity function and the cubing function as "NOT compatible" charts on the real line? If not, could you please explain what motivates the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible" charts and "non-compatible" charts? And, by the way, the equator is ordinarily interpreted to be a great circle, not the disk it bounds.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes! That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi Ted, by compatible chart I mean charts which when they overlap have an equivalent notion of differentiability, which corresponds to maps like $\varphi_{\alpha} \circ \varphi_{\beta}^{-1}$ being smooth. Also, I have edited the question to address your concern, thanks!

Comment: It depends on if you mean $C^\infty$ compatible or, e.g., $C^0$ compatible. If you mean $C^\infty$ compatible, then it is easy to construct what you want. Just compose your favorite chart with a homomorphism between open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x, y)$ denote Cartesian coordinates on the plane. Smooth homeomorphisms such as
\begin{align*}
  \phi_{0}(x, y) &= (x, y), \\
  \phi_{1}(x, y) &= (x^{3}, y), \\
  \phi_{2}(x, y) &= (x, y^{3}), \\
  \phi_{3}(x, y) &= (x^{3}, y^{3}),
\end{align*}
among an infinite-dimensional space's worth of other examples, define pairwise-incompatible charts on the plane.

To get charts on the sphere, it suffices to pick two of these and follow them by a *compatible* pair of charts for the sphere, such as stereographic projection from the north pole and stereographic projection from the south pole.

The conceptual points are:

- All mappings in question are homeomorphisms of the plane to itself, or from a punctured sphere to the plane;
- Incompatible charts composed with compatible charts are incompatible. (Contrapositively: Compatible charts composed with compatible charts are compatible.)

<>

One doesn't normally see this type of example mentioned explicitly: It's typical behavior for charts of topological manifolds (homeomorphisms are "rarely" diffeomorphisms), and inapplicable to the study of smooth manifolds (no smooth atlas contains two incompatible charts).